# Creating a Stack Overflow account instead of “Sign in with Google”

Tags: support, login, google

When I first signed up to Stack Overflow, I just registered quickly using my Google account.

However, as I've become more interested in the Stack Overflow community (and intend to more when work permits), I don't want to be overly dependent on my Google account, and would prefer to have my own unrelated Stack Overflow account.

I know I don't have much reputation points yet but, is there a way I can transfer my profile across to use a non-Google login so I don't have to start again from zero?

Comment: Why not just add a Stack Exchange login and remove the Google login after that? You are not required to keep it.

Comment: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, to clarify, Stack Exchange does not have it's own dedicated login system*.

Rather, it supports then OpenId and OAuth2.0 standards, which means you can use any external login provider that supports either standard.

The best part of this option is you can have multiple logins for a single account.  This means if you want to change logins (either by choice or by necessity), you can do so without having to change accounts or transfer anything to a new account.

To add a new login, just click on Settings from your profile and find the "MyLogins" option.

> [image]

From the MyLogins page, you will see all of the logins currently associated with your account and there will be a link to add a new login, and from there you'll be able to select a range of options.

The only problem is adding a Stack Exchange login to an existing account is not as obvious as it should, and there has never been a solid explanation as to why this is the case.

The highest voted answer in [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704) does explain the process for a workaround to add an SE login to an existing account.

`*` - Stack Exchange does have a login system that supports OpenId.  It is not a dedicated login system for Stack Exchange sites and can be used as an external login for other site that supports OpenId.

Comment: Thanks very much @psubsee2003 - I hadn't even heard of this OpenID! I'll register now - for anyone else looking for the same can find out if you've already got one and/or 'roll your own' OpenID here: http://openid.net/get-an-openid/

Comment: I'm confused. I can log in to stackoverflow by giving it my email address (as a username) and my password. How does that not indicate a dedicated login system?

Comment: Is this still true, I have trouble getting this to work

Comment: This still works in 2023 - I just added GitHub Login and ditched the previous Google Login afterwards. Thanks @psubsee2003 