# How to change (transfer) my Gmail account to default Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, login, accounts

I am using my Google account to login to Stack Overflow I need to use same account to login directly to Stack Overflow without logging in to Google account?

Is it possible or not?

Comment: You can add additional credentials to your account, e.g. a Stack Exchange OpenID login: http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: Related, but not quite a dup [Creating Stack Overflow account instead of “Sign in with Google”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290773/creating-stack-overflow-account-instead-of-sign-in-with-google)

Answer (score 10):

That's not possible.

If you're using your Google credentials to login to Stack Overflow, you're going to have to use Google's authentication.

Otherwise, you'd be entering your Google credentials on a site that is not (owned by) Google. That's asking for someone to steal your credentials.

---

As [Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn) [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339156/how-to-changetransfer-my-gmail-account-to-default-stackoverflow-account#comment419048_339156), it *is* possible to add multiple login credentials to your account.
Have a look at [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) for some more information:

> [image]

Comment: The question should be "Can one later change the way he logs in to SO? Maybe move from Google account to a dedicated SE account where the password is stored in SE servers?"

Comment: @CinCout: If that's the question, the OP should've asked that...

Comment: That was my question, and hence I wrote "the question should be..."

Comment: You can't directly add a Stack Exchange login to an existing account anymore.  Process is a bit more complicated, but I'm not sure why.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290773/creating-stack-overflow-account-instead-of-sign-in-with-google

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah, there's a link at the bottom of the help page, pointing to the page you linked.

Comment: @Stijn thanks, didn't know they added that to that page - but since the OP specifically asked about an SE login, probably worth pointing out

Comment: You could always create a new account with a Stack Exchange login, request a merge, then delete the google login.